# Is my Realtime Clock Locking Up My Arduino? If so, how would I solve it?

Tags: arduino-mega

I am having a very strange issue with the realtime clock in Arduino that I cannot seem to solve.  Basically, I have a program that logs data from a terrarium kit and saves each session to an SD card as a file named after the time the program started.  0

The problem with the program is that the code hangs on the statement before the setup section: “DateTime now = RTC.now().”  The realtime clock appears to be functioning correctly with the example program which makes this issue even more strange.  I am unsure if this is purely a software or hardware issue.  From scouring the internet, I have found people with a similar problem to mine where the RTC will freeze up the i2c bus on the Arduino.  However, I am unsure whether this is the issue plaguing me.  If this is indeed the issue plaguing my program, unsure of how to work around it.  I found an online solution here, however my program freezes upon launch so this would not work for me.

So far, I have tried:
-Replacing the coin-cell battery in the realtime clock (I am using 3 volt batteries)
-Replacing the datalogger shield with a new one
-Replacing the Arduino with a new one
-Checking to make sure that the jumpers were correctly soldered to the datalogger shield (Adafruit support checked mine through images and said they looked good)

I am running this program on IDE Version 1.6.9 with a program with the newer Adafruit datalogger shield on the Arduino Mega.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
//The libraries we need for our terrarium kit
//Download and install them all at this link:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10XAFdYmnyz0dg9I6YYj80vJlHebFIZhN
#include <OneWire.h> //Import OneWire library
#include <DallasTemperature.h> //Import DallasTemperature library
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h> //Import Adafruit Sensor library
#include <DHT.h> //Import first part of the DHT library
#include <TimerOne.h> //Import TimerOne library
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>  //this refers to an old SD library needed specifically for 
#include "RTClib.h"  //this is from the rtc example folder code


//SD Card & Realtime Clock: Initialization
File logfile;
RTC_DS1307 RTC;

//Humidity Sensor: Constants
//This #define defines the pin that the DHT is plugged into
#define DHT_PIN 2 
//This #define defines the type of the DHT
#define DHT_TYPE DHT22
//This tells the code that a DHT is plugged into port DHT_PIN and the DHT is of type DHT_TYPE
DHT dht(DHT_PIN, DHT_TYPE);

//Moisture Sensor: Variables
int MS_sigPin = A5; //Set the signal pin as analog pin 5
int MS_digPin = 7; //Set the digital pin as 2
float MS_upper = 0; //Declare highest value variable

//Other variables
int measurementNumber = 1; //Number of measurements taken

//Filename:
  DateTime now = RTC.now(); //Initialize the RTC
//  String seconds = (String)(now.second());  //Stores the seconds from the RTC upon setup as a string
 const String minutes = (String)(now.minute()); //Stores the seconds from the RTC upon setup as a string
 const String hours = (String)(now.hour());  //Stores the seconds from the RTC upon setup as a string
 const String days = (String)(now.day());  //Stores the seconds from the RTC upon setup as a string
 const String months = (String)(now.month());  //Stores the seconds from the RTC upon setup as a string
 const String years = (String)(now.year());  //Stores the seconds from the RTC upon setup as a string
 const String filename = "D_" + minutes + hours + days + months + years; //Create the file name as a timestamp


void setup() {

  int chipSelect = 10; //chipSelect pin for the SD card

  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200); //Set the baud rate at 56700
//If RTC is already updated, the below is commented out
  RTC.begin();
  RTC.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));//this is to force rtc update
//  if (!RTC.isrunning()) {
//    
//    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running! Starting it now.");
//    RTC.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
//   
//  }// end rtc if

//{
//The below is copied from wired, contains a second try, hoping for sd success herein.
 pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(chipSelect, HIGH);
 SD.begin(chipSelect);
//  if (!SD.begin(10, 11, 12, 13)) {
//    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
//    delay(50);
//    Serial.println("Trying again...");
//    if (!SD.begin(50, 51, 52, 53)) {
//      Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
//    }
//  }


 /******************************** CSV FORMAT ******************************/

//  Serial.print("Current Position: ");
//  Serial.println(logfile.position());
  if(logfile.position() == 0)//Below print header line for datafile
  logfile.println("Unix Time, Date, Time, Light, Humidity, Temperature");
  //logfile.println("uni,date,time,Temperature");

  /**************************************************************************/

//  sensors.begin();
//  sensors.setResolution(12);

  //Humidity Sensor:
   dht.begin();

  //Moisture Sensor:
  pinMode(MS_sigPin, OUTPUT); //Set the signal pin as an output
  pinMode(MS_digPin, OUTPUT); //Set the digital pin as an output
  digitalWrite(MS_digPin, HIGH); //Turn the digital pin on

  Serial.println("DIP THE MOISTURE SENSOR IN A CUP OF WATER MAKING SURE NOT TO SUBMERGE THE TOP OF IT INTO THE WATER, ENTER IN ANY KEY WHEN YOU ARE READY TO CALIBRATE"); //Print out useful information
  while (Serial.available() == 0) //Hang the program until the user inputs a key to continue
  {

  }
  Serial.println("Starting Calibration"); //Print out useful information
  Timer1.initialize(1000000); //Initialize an interrupt every 1 second
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(Calibrate); //When the interrupt is called run the “Calibrate” function

}
//Calibrate the moisture sensor
void Calibrate() //Function to calibrate the sensor
{
if (analogRead(MS_sigPin) > MS_upper) //If the value read by the sensor is higher than the past highest value
{
 MS_upper = analogRead(MS_sigPin); //Set the current value as the new highest value 
  }
}

void loop() {

//Photocell: Variables
int photocellPin = A0; // the cell and 10K pulldown are connected to a0

  char fileCharStorage[(filename.length()+5)]; //+4 Characters to include ".csv"
  filename.toCharArray(fileCharStorage, filename.length()+5);
  fileCharStorage[filename.length()] = 'V'; //Set the file name
  fileCharStorage[filename.length()-1] = 'S'; //Set the file name
  fileCharStorage[filename.length()-2] = 'C'; //Set the file name
  fileCharStorage[filename.length()-3] = '.'; //Set the file name
  Serial.println(filename); //Print out the filename
  Serial.println(sizeof(fileCharStorage)); //Print the length of the array storing the file name 
  logfile = SD.open(fileCharStorage, FILE_WRITE);  //Creates (or opens) a file names "MMHHDDMMYYYY.CSV"

  if (logfile)
  {
    Serial.println("The SD Card is functioning properly");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("A Critical Error occured while trying to initialize the SD Card!");
  }
  //Realtime Clock
  DateTime now = RTC.now();

 //Photocell:
 int photocellReading = analogRead(photocellPin); //Variable that stores the amount of light detected by the photocell as an integer

  // This code gets the humidity from the DHT
  float dhtHumidity = dht.readHumidity();
  /*
  This code gets the temperature from the DHT
  */
  float dhtTemperature = dht.readTemperature();

  Serial.println(""); //Text Formatting
  Serial.println("Starting New Measurement (" + (String)measurementNumber + ")");
  Serial.println(""); //Text Formatting
  delay(1000);

  //Print out data from the number of measurements taken
  Serial.println("The Arduino has been active for " + (String)((measurementNumber*10)-10) + " seconds");
  measurementNumber++;

  //Print out data from the RTC
    Serial.print("Unix Time (Seconds since 1/1/1970): ");
    Serial.print(now.unixtime()); // seconds since 1/1/1970
    Serial.println(", ");
    Serial.print("RTC time: ");
    Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print("/");
    Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print(",");
    Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("");

  //Photocell:
  Serial.println("Data from the photocell:");
  Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
  Serial.print(photocellReading); // the raw analog reading 

  if (photocellReading < 10) { 
  Serial.println(" - Dark"); //says that if any number is lower than 10 then it prints out dark.
  } else if (photocellReading < 200) {
  Serial.println(" - Dim"); //says that if any number is lower than 200 then it prints out dim.
  } else if (photocellReading < 500) { 
  Serial.println(" - Light"); //says that if any number is lower than 500 then it prints out light.
  } else if (photocellReading < 800) { 
  Serial.println(" - Bright"); //says that if any number is lower than 800 then it prints out bright
  } else { 
  Serial.println(" - Very bright"); //says that if any number higher than 800 then it prints out very bright
}
  Serial.println("");

// Humidity Sensor:
  Serial.println("Data from the humidity sensor:");
  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(dhtHumidity);
  Serial.print(" %, Temp: ");
  Serial.print(dhtTemperature);
  Serial.println(" Celsius");
  Serial.println("");


  //Moisture Sensor:
  Serial.println("Data from the moisture sensor:");
  float percent = (analogRead(MS_sigPin)/MS_upper)*100; //Calculate moisture percentage
  Serial.println("Moisture = " + (String)percent + "%"); //Print out the moisture percentage

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("--------------------------------------------------");

    //Log everything onto the SD card
    logfile.print(now.unixtime()); // seconds since 1/1/1970
    logfile.print(", ");
    logfile.print(now.month(), DEC);
    logfile.print("/");
    logfile.print(now.day(), DEC);
    logfile.print("/");
    logfile.print(now.year(), DEC);
    logfile.print(",");
    logfile.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    logfile.print(":");
    logfile.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    logfile.print(":");
    logfile.print(now.second(), DEC);
    logfile.print(", ");    
    logfile.print(photocellReading);
    logfile.print(", ");    
    logfile.print(dhtHumidity);
    logfile.print(", ");    
    logfile.print(dhtTemperature);
    logfile.println();    
    logfile.close();
//  Delay by 1+9 (10) seconds between measurements
  delay(9000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you can't call `RTC.now()` before setup like that.

It would be helpful if you told us what RTC you were using, and provided a link to the library you were using for it.

At a guess, since I don't have that info, you should probably change the declaration like this:

```
  //Filename:
  DateTime now;
```

And then in your `setup()`:

```
RTC.begin();

if (!RTC.isrunning()) {
  Serial.println("RTC is NOT running! Starting it now.");
  RTC.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));  
} // end rtc if
now = RTC.now(); //Initialize the RTC
```